# how to disable horizontal scroll for a uiwebview in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I need to display a document in a uiwebview.I was succeeded in displaying it,but i need to move the webview only vertically.I don't want the horizontal scrolling how can i achieve this..Please help me

Answer (score 3):

In your HTML, add the following in the `<head>` section of your HTML.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: Then you need to inject that line into the html, either before you load it into the web view, or using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:. (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style>body{background-color:transparent;word-wrap:break-word;}</style></head><body>%@</body></html>",htmlBody];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:test baseURL:nil];
```